# Insercao de Objetos selecionados em Array

Tags: java, array

Estou fazendo um programa de Corridas de Formula 1, o meu programa realiza a leitura de vários arquivos de corrida, e cria os objetos da prova. Necessito implantar neste programa uma classe que  possua um array para guardar apenas os Pilotos que possuam pontos acima de 0, e caso o piloto já esteja no array, a sua pontuação deve ser atualizada, porém, os objetos não estão sendo criados no array:

Parte da Classe main:

```
public class Controle {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Temporada2013 temporada = new Temporada2013();
        File arquivos[];
        File diretorio = new File("/Users/leonardobruksch/NetBeansProjects/Corridas");
        arquivos = diretorio.listFiles();

        for(int a=0;a<arquivos.length;a++){
            Provas prova = new Provas();
        try {
            FileReader fr = new FileReader(arquivos[a]);
            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String line = in.readLine();
            line = in.readLine();
            while (line != null) {
                String result[] = line.split(";");
                int x = Integer.parseInt(result[6]);
                prova.inserePiloto(result[0], result[1], result[2], result[3], result[4], result[5], x);
                if(x > 0)
                    temporada.inserePilotosPontuados(result[1], result[2], x);
                line = in.readLine();
            }
```

Parte da classe Temporada2013 que realiza a insercao:

```
public class Temporada2013 {

    Piloto[] pontuados = new Piloto[30];

    public void inserePilotosPontuados(String driver, String team, int points) {
        for(int i=0;i<getLast();i++){
            if(pontuados[i].getDriver().equalsIgnoreCase(driver)){
                pontuados[i].setPoints(pontuados[i].getPoints()+points);
                return;
            }

        }
        pontuados[getLast()] = new Piloto(driver, team, points);
    }

    private int getLast(){
        int last = 0;
        for(int i=0;i<pontuados.length;i++){
            if(pontuados[i] == null)
                last = i;
                return last;
        }
        return last;
    }
```

O que esta ocorrendo é que o método acima, apôs ser executado e exibido, está criando apenas um objeto no array, ao invés de criar vários.

Comment: O código chega a entrar no método `temporada.inserePilotosPontuados`?

Comment: Sim, pois em varios casos a variável x(result[6]) que foi transformada para inteiro, e maior que 0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Acredito que o problema esteja aqui:

```
private int getLast(){
    int last = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<pontuados.length;i++){
        if(pontuados[i] == null)
            last = i;
            return last;
    }
    return last;
}
```

Como você pode ver, o `if` **não possuí chaves** `{}`. As chaves são usadas para delimitar blocos de código. Omitindo as chaves, você faz com que apenas a instrução após o `if` faça parte dele.

Resumindo... removendo as chaves, você remove a capacidade do seu `if` de ter várias instruções.

Explicar com o código é mais fácil. Veja o trecho do seu código abaixo:

```
int last = 0;

for(int i=0;i<getLast();i++){
    if(pontuados[i] == null)
        last = i;
        return last;
}
```

Fazer isso, seria o mesmo que fazer:

```
int last = 0;

for(int i=0;i<getLast();i++){
    if(pontuados[i] == null) {
        last = i;
    }

    return last;
}
```

Assim, o `for` acima vai retornar `last` logo na primeira iteração. Como `last = 0`, seu método vai retornar `0` sempre.
Retornar `0` vai causar um efeito colateral no método `inserePilotosPontuados`, onde:

```
pontuados[getLast()] = new Piloto(driver, team, points);
```

É o mesmo que fazer:

```
pontuados[0] = new Piloto(driver, team, points);
```

O código abaixo deve funcionar sem problemas:

```
private int getLast() {
    int last = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < pontuados.length; i++) {
        if (pontuados[i] == null) {
            last = i;
            return last;
        }
    }

    return last;
}
```

Comment: Sim Gabriel!! Seria isso mesmo o problema, foi um erro idiota e causado pela falta de atenção, mas que acontece! hahaha valeu!

Comment: Hehe. Mas olha só, te recomendo usar `{}` sempre. Sei que, dependendo do ponto de vista, pode custar uma linha de código, deixar o código "mais feio", etc. Mas torna o código mais legível e menos suscetível a erros desse tipo.

Comment: Óptima resposta, confesso que perdi um tempinho e não tinha reparado. Um boa questão, pra mim, é quando o array estiver completo, como esta função se comporta?

Comment: Acredito que vá retornar `0` também.